# copy/paste text in Flash with formatting

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

in ActionScript-2 is there any way the html text can be copied and pasted without formatting loss.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: what kind of textfield are you working with? Static? Dynamic? Input?

Comment: Hi Brain  - I have one selectable textfield with HTML formatted text..want to copy and paste this text to another input textfield without loosing any formating..want to achieve all this in AS 2.0 to support a legacy product

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in Flash specifically or in Flex? There's Rich Text components that will probably handle what you want.

But otherwise, I believe there is this property you can set on your textfield:
yourTextField.useRichTextClipboard = true;

Haven't tested but hope this works! :)

Comment: Thanks bigp..i wanted to do this in Flash (with AS 2.0 not AS 3.0 unfortunately)...wondering if there is a way to do it in AS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have read this webpage recently and there is a part saying "In addition to loading plain text, it is possible to load HTML formatted text, not all HTML tags are supported, but most of the common ones are. To load an HTML formatted text file it is necessary to activate HTML for the specific tag and then assign our HTML codes to the .htmlText property of our text field instead of the regular .text property this way:"

**Here is the link:**
[Loading External Texts into Flash Using the LoadVars() Class](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/loadvars_bc/)